# Forward slash not detected in "grep" command

Tags: shell-script, shell, grep, slash

I have a sql query in a text file and it has a line that looks like:

```
PARTITION BY (date_key // 100000000);
```

Now, I want to replace the two forward slashes with the word "DIV".

For that, I did the following in a shell script:

```
strg=$(grep "PARTITION BY" $entry)    ## $entry has the file_name
strg2=$(echo "$strg" | sed 's%\/\/%DIV%g')
```

But it did not work as I wanted. On further probing, I got to know that the forward slashes are not even being discovered.

`echo "$strg"` gives `PARTITION BY (date_key );`
I also tried

`printf ">%s<\n" "$strg"` and

`printf "%q\n" "$strg"`

but the outputs are:

`>PARTITION BY (date_key );<` and

`PARTITION\ BY\ \(date_key\ \)\;` respectively.

But when I do `grep "PARTITION BY" <file_name>` on the command line, I get the correct output:

```
PARTITION BY (date_key // 100000000);
```

Can someone please point out what I am missing?

Comment: Why did you escape the slashes in `sed 's%\/\/%DIV%g'`? Either you use `%`as separator and you don't need to escape them: `sed 's%//%DIV%g'` or you do the classical `sed 's/\/\//DIV/g'` And `echo $strg` gives the whole line in my bash.

Comment: Your code seems to work for me on MSYS2 using GNU grep 3.0. Perhaps you have a buggy version of grep?

Comment: @Philippos I will take what you said, but the point of concern is is why is "// 100000000" not coming up in the grep. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I can't reproduce it. Maybe try without the `grep`and simply do `strg2=$(sed '/PARTITIONED BY/s%//%DIV%' $entry)`

Comment: If this is mac with old grep (2.27 i think), it is known that this mac grep is QUITE  buggy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep`  will detect the `//`:

```
$ echo 'PARTITION BY (date_key // 100000000);' | grep '//'
PARTITION BY (date_key // 100000000);
```

`sed` will replace them:

```
$ echo 'PARTITION BY (date_key // 100000000);' | sed 's%//%DIV%'
PARTITION BY (date_key DIV 100000000);
```

To replace `//` with `DIV` on every line that matches `PARTITION BY`:

```
$ sed '/PARTITION BY/s%//%DIV%' filename
```